# Android custom view attributes - 'color' as attribute name disallowed

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-xml

I've made a simple custom view, a "ColorSwatch". It's circular, shows the assigned color and if that color has transparency, the color is drawn atop a checker pattern. The view works fine.

My problem is that when I define the custom attributes for the swatch (in `values/attrs_color_swatch_view.xml`), I can't specify an attribute named "color". The compiler complains that color is already defined, and points me to my colors.xml file. As a workaround, I called the parameter `swatchColor`, but I'd prefer it to simply be `color`.

The file: `values/attrs_color_swatch_view.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ColorSwatchView">
        <attr name="swatchColor" format="color"/><!-- would prefer to simply be 'color', not 'swatchColor' -->
        <attr name="selectionThickness" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="isSelected" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="selectionColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="alphaCheckerSize" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Is there a way to use the attribute name `color`? Or is it a reserved keyword? Is there a way to namespace it somehow to my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `color` for the same reason you can't use `background`. They are already defined in the android namespace.

So how to use `color` or any other attribute name that's reserved ? By using the ones that's already defined, and not creating new ones.

Instead of :

```
<attr name="swatchColor" format="color"/>
```

use this:

```
<attr name="android:color"/>
```

Always make sure that you use the ones supplied by android. Only if you think it doesn't suit your needs, go ahead and create your own attribute.