# Android Attribute has already been defined

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a custom view with an attribute named `borderWidth`. When i try to run my app i get the error:

> E:\Android Studio Projects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
>   Error:(341) Attribute "borderWidth" has already been defined

In the `values.xml` file that it points to, i can see that `borderWidth` is already being used for the default `FloatingActionButton` and a couple other default android widgets:

```
<style name="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/design_fab_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="fabSize">auto</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/design_fab_elevation</item>
    <item name="pressedTranslationZ">@dimen/design_fab_translation_z_pressed</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">@dimen/design_fab_border_width</item>
</style>
```

Can i reuse this name for my view or do i have to rename it?

**Edit**

This is the entire `attrs.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--<attr name="borderWidth" format="float" />-->

    <declare-styleable name="ScrollingLineGraph">
        <attr name="unitsX" format="float" />
        <attr name="unitsY" format="float" />

        <attr name="scaleY" format="float" />
        <attr name="scaleX" format="float" />

        <!--<attr name="borderWidth" format="float" />-->
        <attr name="scaleWidth" format="float" />

        <attr name="borderColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="scaleColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="lineColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="highlightColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="labelColor" format="color" />

        <attr name="labelSize" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is the layout file where my custom view is being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_main"
                                                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Other views -->

    <com.tycho.app.simplegraphs.ui.ScrollingLineGraph
        android:id="@+id/graph1"
        custom:unitsX="10000"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <com.tycho.app.simplegraphs.ui.ScrollingLineGraph
        android:id="@+id/graph2"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        custom:lineColor="#FF0000"
        custom:unitsX="10000"
        custom:highlightColor="#80FF0000"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <!-- Other views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699561/android-custom-view-attributes-color-as-attribute-name-disallowed/33810203#33810203) states, the only way to use a particular name that has already been used by android is to re-use it. This is not suitable in this situation however because my attributes have a different meaning from the standard android one, so i will just have to rename mine.

So i will be renaming `borderWidth` to `graphBorderWidth`.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the attribute. This is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>

    <declare-styleable name="View1">
        <attr name="textSize"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="View2">
        <attr name="textSize"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

For more info https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Comment: I tried that but it gives the following error: `Error: Found item Attr/borderWidth more than one time`

Comment: You can use a custom namespace. Look here https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr . Have you add your custom attributes into a file called attrs.xml?

Comment: I already have the namespace set up like this: `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` but the error is still there.

Comment: Strange. If you can post the xml file where you declare the attribute and the xml where you use the namespace it will help everyone is able to resolve the issue.